# Authorize just a fingerprint?

Tags: ssh

I noticed `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` expects a full public key to be added in order to work. Is there a way to accept just a fingerprint as opposed to the long version?

Comment: Can you explain how this question is related to programming? Perhaps you would be better off asking on [security.se], [crypto.se], [su], or [unix.se]. I would also suggest adding some background information about _why_ you only have a fingerprint to work with.

Comment: @200_success: I thought this would fit in within "software tools commonly used by programmers" here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. For pubkey authentication, you need the whole public key to do public-key cryptography on the data you received from the client to verify, he has the private part of the public key. You have no way how to get this from just fingerprint.

Comment: Isn't the public key sent over the network anyway? I thought that the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys part is redundant and is used only for authorization.

Comment: Yes. It is send over the network, but using only the fingerprint (considering MD5), you would have 128 bit of information instead of 2048 bit whole from RSA key (current normal size) and this approach would be dangerous for conflicts (and MD5 is quite liable for them). Currently PK brute-force attacks are not worth even trying, but it there would be only fingerprint verified, you are getting much bigger chance you will hit some keys.

Comment: I guess that if there's any reasonable risk of collision, the algorithm shouldn't be used for any security-critical hashing anyway. Somehow it's securie enough to verify authenticity on the first connection, but not for authorization?

Comment: You can say it that way. MD5 is getting slowly obsolete everywhere, since it is not considered as much secure and upstream is moving to fingerprints using SHA256. But it is not one-day job since there are many clients and servers running rusty old software versions. Checking host fingerprint has much smaller attack surface than authentication itself so there is not so great risk. Though interesting idea.